# Facing Issue to Convert HTML Template into Laravel Application

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-8

Guys please help me to solve this problem. I'm trying to return the view to the Home Page by using the HomeController but Home Page is empty.

Im adding Home.Blade.Php File Image, Web Route File, and HomeController. Please look at this and tell me where I go wrong.

Web Route File
[image]
Home.Blade.Php
[image]
HomeController
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is related to blade templates names.

blades templates are named in snake-case usually.

Why don`t you try to rename your blade template to` home.blade.php`and adjust in the controller`return view('frontend.home')`;

Comment: I try to rename the blade template as you said but still, it won't show any results.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post all your code as text  to see your code in detail, and include your template. Anyway you should see your laravel log to track posible errors.